# Material Design Floating Button (FAB) Blocking RecyclerView

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

I'm facing a strange issue while trying to use a material design FAB button in my app. I'm using this library (https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton).

My activity xml has a RecyclerView and the FAB. But the FAB is actually blocking the lower portion of the entire screen. Something like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtEcb.png

It can be seen in the picture that the RecyclerView containing the cards is being blocked by the Floating Button. Here's the code I'm using:

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        class="com.rubberduck.zoop.fragments.OffersFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_enter_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_offer" />

    <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_place_white_24dp"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/color_accent"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/color_accent_pressed"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/ripple" />

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_offer.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.rubberduck.zoop.fragments.OffersFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_offers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/card_offer"
        layout="@layout/offer_card" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a `LinearLayout` as the container for your `fragment` and `FloatingActionButton`, items do not overlap: The `LinearLayout` gives the full width to each component when you use `orientation="vertical"`. Instead, as per the [FloatingActionButton readme](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton/blob/master/README.md), you should use a `FrameLayout` (which allows items to overlap - ensuring the `FloatingActionButton` appears above the `RecyclerView`):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        class="com.rubberduck.zoop.fragments.OffersFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_enter_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_offer" />

    <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_place_white_24dp"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/color_accent"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/color_accent_pressed"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/ripple" />

</FrameLayout>
```